# Como armazeno valores como objetos em Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Como posso armazenar os valores da minha classe?

Toda vez que clico nos botões a minha classe parece ser instanciada novamente.

**Minha classe:**

```
public class Partida
{
    public string[] linha1 = new string[3];
    public string[] linha2 = new string[3];
    public string[] linha3 = new string[3];
    public string[] diagonal1 = new string[3];
    public string[] diagonal2 = new string[3];
    public string[] coluna1 = new string[3];
    public string[] coluna2 = new string[3];
    public string[] coluna3 = new string[3];

    public Partida()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            linha1[i] = "";
            linha2[i] = "";
            linha3[i] = "";
            coluna1[i] = "";
            coluna2[i] = "";
            coluna3[i] = "";
            diagonal1[i] = "";
            diagonal2[i] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Minha Web Page**

```
namespace prova.jogo_da_velha
{
    public partial class jogodavelha : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        Partida partida = new Partida();

        //True = X False = O
        bool turno = true;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turno)
            {
                partida.linha1[0] = "x";
                partida.coluna1[0] = "x";
                partida.diagonal1[0] = "x";
                Button11.Text = "X";
                turno = false;
            }
            else
            {
                partida.linha1[0] = "o";
                partida.coluna1[0] = "o";
                partida.diagonal1[0] = "o";
                Button11.Text = "O";
                turno = true;
            }
        }

        protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (turno)
            {
                partida.linha1[1] = "x";
                partida.coluna2[0] = "x";
                Button12.Text = "X";
                turno = false;
            }
            else
            {
                partida.linha1[1] = "o";
                partida.coluna2[0] = "o";
                Button12.Text = "O";
                turno = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar seu código (coloque partes relevantes, nem mais, nem menos). Fica difícil para as pessoas trabalharem com uma *screenshot*. E por favor, aprenda fazer títulos descritos do seu problema, não é para jogar as *tags* nele. Além disso escolha as *tags* com mais cuidado. Você terá dificuldade de ser ajudado se não colaborar. E tente deixar mais clara a pergunta, eu não entendi o que você quer efetivamente. Me pareceu que você quer saber algo não relacionado com seu problema.

Comment: Assim está melhor?

Comment: Acertei um problema de formatação. DÊ uma olhada como ficou a edição. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/42407/revisions

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa entender o ciclo de vida de uma página no Web Forms (veja [este link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Toda vez que o navegador pede para carregar uma página, o ASP.NET cria uma instância da sua classe, faz a operação correspondente ao ciclo da sua página (exemplo, se for a primeira vez, provavelmente vai ser um `Page_Load` com a propriedade `IsPostBack = false`) e depois joga fora este objeto. Se for uma outra ação, além de chamar o `Page_Load`, ele seta a propriedade `IsPostBack` e depois chama seu evento específico (como no caso, `Button11_Click`).

Para que uma informação possa estar **salvar** (ou seja, persistir) entre uma chamada e outra, você precisa armazenar as informações que você quer que **continuem salvas** em objetos especiais. Neste caso sua instância da classe `partida` e a variável `turno`.

Estes objetos são:

- **View State** - Guarda informações relativas à página que você está. Estas informações acabam indo para o usuário de forma embaralhada em um `<input hidden`, e o ASP.NET coloca automaticamente isso e recupera de novo no `Page_Load`. Geralmente os botões, textos da tela já usam estas informações de uma maneira ou outra. É bom usar para informações relativas à coisas da tela mesmo: que botão está clicado, que texto está inserido, etc.
- **Session** - Guarda no servidor instâncias de objetos que devem ser guardadas temporariamente enquanto o usuário está logado. É mais seguro porque estas informações não vão para o HTML, ficam só no servidor. É o local ideal para você armazenar estas propriedades. Elas são compartilhadas entre páginas.. então se você setar um `Session['partida'] = new Partida()`, outras páginas também poderão recuperá-las. Este objeto é criado 1 por usuário que acessa o site,

Tem outros, como o uma "sessão" especial chamada `Application`, que é um objeto relativo à todos os usuários conectados, e não somente 1.